# Powermail 3 keeps reloading page and not sending mail

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I've a very basic Powermail installation running. No special configuration.
The form is reloading after submit, but not sending a mail or showing confirmation page. I've some required field which are working / showing errors if not provived.
As the form has no special config, I'm not sure what more information I could provide. Powermail version is the latest 3.0.2 and TYPO3 is latest 7.6.6.

Any hint is really appreciated! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Powermail redirects back to the form if relevant POST-params are missing. This happens if there is a serverside redirect or a wrong baseUrl or something like that. I would open the browser console and check if there are any redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Kellner for this hint! Helps me alot to find a solution. For the record: it was my fault - obviously.
In my case the problem was caused by a misconfiguration in realurl which resulted in missing parameters as Alex mentioned.